# Rabbitmq is not joined in the cluster properly

Tags: rabbitmq, redhat, openstack, rabbitmqctl

Cluster Status :

In controller-2, "running_nodes, cluster_name, partitions, and alarms" are not showing in the cluster_status output so please check and give me your suggestion to recover this issue.

controller-2:

```
    Cluster status of node 'rabbit@overcloud-controller-2' ... 
    [{nodes,[{disc,['rabbit@overcloud-controller-0', 
                    'rabbit@overcloud-controller-1', 
                    'rabbit@overcloud-controller-2']}]}, 
     {alarms,[]}]
```

controller-0:

```
    Cluster status of node 'rabbit@overcloud-controller-0' ... 
    [{nodes,[{disc,['rabbit@overcloud-controller-0', 
                    'rabbit@overcloud-controller-1']}]}, 
     {running_nodes,['rabbit@overcloud-controller-1', 
                     'rabbit@overcloud-controller-0']}, 
     {cluster_name,<<"rabbit@overcloud-controller-0.localdomain">>}, 
     {partitions,[]}, 
     {alarms,[{'rabbit@overcloud-controller-1',[]}, 
              {'rabbit@overcloud-controller-0',[]}]}]
```

controller-1:

```
    Cluster status of node 'rabbit@overcloud-controller-1' ... 
    [{nodes,[{disc,['rabbit@overcloud-controller-0', 
                    'rabbit@overcloud-controller-1']}]}, 
     {running_nodes,['rabbit@overcloud-controller-0', 
                     'rabbit@overcloud-controller-1']}, 
     {cluster_name,<<"rabbit@overcloud-controller-0.localdomain">>}, 
     {partitions,[]}, 
     {alarms,[{'rabbit@overcloud-controller-0',[]}, 
              {'rabbit@overcloud-controller-1',[]}]}] 
[stack@undercloud (stackrc) ~]$
```

Comment: Have you checked the RabbitMQ log? Is the time on all three controllers synchronized?

Comment: how we need to check ?

Comment: The log's location depends on your configuration. For time synchronization, check the status of whatever NTP service is deployed.